# MySQLi Inner Join issue

Tags: php, select, mysqli, inner-join

I have two tables on a forum that I am referencing via a SELECT query. One table is the phpBB_users table, which holds the basic data for a member while the second table, phpbb_profile_fields_data, holds details such as address, email, phone, etc. Both tables use user_id as the key. My form selects the $smode parameter, which lists the various column headings to search for and the $parameter variable, which enters the actual data to search for. The results are displayed in an HTML table.

Here's my code:

```
$conn = new mysqli('localhost',$user,$pass,$database);

$sql = "SELECT * FROM phpbb_users 
INNER JOIN phpbb_profile_fields_data ON phpbb_users.user_id = phpbb_profile_fields_data.user_id
WHERE   $smode = $parameter
ORDER BY username";
$result = $conn->query($sql);
```

If I select group_id (which is in the phpbb_users table) as my $smode variable and enter a given group number as the $parameter variable, I get a nice listing of the members within that group. If I change the  $smode variable to pf_user_lastname (which is in the phpbb_profile_fields_data table) and enter a common last name I don't get any results. The same holds true if I use username as the $smode variable (which is in the phpbb_users table). I get no results. The group_id column is an integer while the other two are alphanumeric variables but when I change the $smode to pf_mh_year, which is a 4 digit integer in the phpbb_profile_fields_data table, I still don't get any results. I get no error messages in the error_log because $result->num_rows is zero - except for the first case where the listing displays.

Comment: add `echo $sql` to your script and verify the SQL statement in PHPMyAdmin (or any other tool)

Answer (score -1):

I did echo the $sql and it looked fine. But when I tested it in PHPMyAdmin like you suggested it showed that I needed to place the $parameter value in single quotes. Not sure why it worked without them for the one integer column but not the other but either way, everything works now that the quotes are in place.